# User Engagement Fabric vs Firebase

Tags: firebase, session, google-analytics, google-fabric

With Fabric going away in March I know where I can find sessions easily in Fabric Engagement.  I don't see engagement anywhere on my Firebase page.  Could they have changed the name possibly?  Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Try looking in Firebase Distribution ?

Comment: I appreciate it but my distribution is for a beta test basically, I am looking for where can I find how many sesssions my app had